# Pourquoi un « X » à mieux?

Tags: étymologie, orthographe, comparatifs

Je me demandais, pourquoi met-on toujours un "X" à mieux, mais, par exemple, nous ne mettons pas de "X" à lieu (je sais que c'est un nom, mais c'est le premier mot finissant avec « eu » auquel j'ai pensé)? Je peux comprendre que c'est invariable mais pourquoi seulement mieux? (ou peut-être y en a t-il d'autre, mais pour l'instant aucun autre me viens à l'esprit).

Je ne veux pas de parce que c'est ainsi ou quoi que ce soit, mais j'aimerais s'avoir s'il y a une raison historique, un règle de grammaire?

Comment: Et je sais que c'est peut-être une question sans intérêt, mais je détestes rester avec des "parce que c'est ainsi"...

Comment: La question n'est manifestement *pas* sans intérêt, puisqu'elle t'intéresse (et cl-r, mais il s'intéresse à tout alors ça ne compte pas ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Mieux* du latin *melius*, de *melior* "meilleur"
>
> *Lieu* du latin *locus*

... mais *mieux* s'écrivait ***mielz, melz, miex*** au Xe siècle, et rarement *mius*,
... alors que *lieu* (dans sa notion spatiale) s'écrivait ***loc*** au même moment, puis ***leu*** au XIIIe, puis *lieu*.

*Mieux* résulte donc d'une évolution calligraphique différente de celle de *lieu*.

Comment: +1, mais j'aimerai bien ta source pour le Xe s. [Wiki](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mieux) n'est pas aussi précis.

Comment: @YohannV.  http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/lieu ;  http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/mieux , le petit Robert a retenu en plus *mielz*.

Answer (score 4):

> *Mieux* résulte donc d'une évolution calligraphique différente de celle de *lieu*.

L'évolution en question résulte essentiellement des abréviations de scribes.

En effet, dans l'orthographe *miex* que cl-r indique dans sa réponse, le *x* représente en fait la combinaison de lettre *us* (ou possiblement *uz*, voire l'une ou l'autre indifféremment, cela n'a guère d'importance). Ce u est l'évolution normale d'un *-l* en fin de syllabe ou devant une autre consonne (d'où [des alternance comme *-al/-aux*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/19921/926) et *col/cou*).

Plus tard, la signification du *x* ayant été oubliée, on rétablit les *-u* prononcés, mais non écrits, toutefois ce procédé s'appliqua sans restaurer les -*s* présents dans les pluriels d'origine. D'où l'abondance de mots avec pluriels en -*ux* en français moderne cohabitant avec des pluriels en -*us*, qui la plupart du temps sont tout simplement des mots postérieurs à cette évolution phonétique et orthographique.

De fait, **ces deux mots ont la même évolution**, du moment qu'on compare *mieux* non pas au singulier, mais bien au **pluriel** de *lieu*!

Comment: Très intéressant. J'adore ce genre d'explication.