# Pourquoi certains mots se terminant en « -al » ont leur pluriel en « -als » ?

Tags: étymologie, pluriel, histoire, suffixes

Si l'on omet les mots récemment empruntés à l'anglais, tels que « sex-appeal », la règle dit que les mots en « -al » se terminent en « -aux » au pluriel, sauf « aval », « bal », « carnaval », « chacal », « corral », « final », « festival », « récital », « régal » qui se terminent, eux, en « -als » au pluriel.

Historiquement ou étymologiquement, existe-t-il une justification à ces exceptions ?

Comment: "final" au pluriel se dit "finaux", et j'ai un doute pour "corral" => "corraux"... Je crois que la différence vient de l'origine du radical... mais je ne pourrais pas m'avancer plus... :)

Comment: J'admets avoir été un peu paresseux pour la liste et m'être fié au premier lien trouvé sur Google. Ceci dit, [« final » possède les deux formes au pluriel](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?11;s=3810311490;r=1;nat=;sol=0;), mais « [corral](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/corral) » est indiscutablement dans la liste.

Comment: [corral](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/corral_corrals/19415)

[corail/coral](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/corail/19223)

Comment: Plus spéficiquement, les mots qui m'intéressent et qui m'ont poussé à poser cette question sont « bal » et « festival ».

Comment: Pour *chacal*, une étymologie intéressante : http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/chacal

Comment: @Random Quand il est adjectif, mais sinon « un final » « des finals » (bien qu'il soit parfois employé au féminin même en musique). Mais la question ne citant que des noms bien qu'employant « mots  »  il est possible que celui qui a posé la question ne pensait qu'aux noms.  Pour la réponse il faut de toutes façons distinguer adj. et noms.

Comment: Les noms qui font leur pluriel en -als sont d'origine étrangère, et si même d'origine latine,  entrés dans leur emploi actuel en français bien après que la vélarisation en ancien français qui a provoqué le pluriel en -aux. Chacal(s) turc, corral(s) espagnol, festival(s) anglais, final(s) italien, bal(s) italien etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pour faire simple, les mots en -als sont, règle générale, plus récents que les mots en -aux. (Grevisse, 2007, *Le Bon Usage, 14e ed*, §§517,553)

Pour être exact, ces mots sont souvent postérieur à changement phonétique en français qui a transformé en /ou/ (pour être vraiment exact, en /w/) la consonne /l/ lorsqu'elle précédait une autre consonne<sup>(1)</sup>. On retrouve des trace de cette alternance dans d'autres mots:

- *chevelu*/*cheveu* (à l'origine sigulier *chevel*)
- *sol*/*sou* (nom de monnaie), *col*/*cou*
- *châtel*/*château*
- *matériau* (originellement *matérial*, le singulier moderne reconstruit sur le pluriel)
- *universaux* (construit sur un singulier *universal*)

En pratique, la situation est plus compliquées. Ainsi, des mots en -als ont eu un pluriel en -aux (ce fut le cas de *naval*, *fatal*, *natal* et *bal*), et l'inverse s'est également produit (cas de *madrigal* et *piédestal*).

De fait, de nombreux adjectifs dont les grammairiens et dictionnaires insistaient autrefois qu'ils avaient un pluriel en -als, voire (!) qu'on devait éviter de les employer au masculin pluriel,<sup>(2)</sup> semblent vouloir passer de -als à -aux: Grevisse cite en particulier *glacial*, *tribal*, *marial* et *final*...

---

1. Le -x servait à l'origine d’abréviation à la séquence *us*, et a été erronément préservé même une fois le *u* rétabli.
2. Une exhortation qui ne fait souvent que révéler une forte hésitation dans l'usage. Je décèle (personnellement) le même phénomène dans l'insistance des grammaires à affirmer que les verbes en -traire sont défectifs. Si c'est défendable pour *traire* lui-même, divers auteurs n'ont pas hésité à reconstruire un passé simple pour les autres verbes de ce groupe, d'usage beaucoup plus fréquent.

Comment: Merci, cela clarifie assez bien tout ce que je me posais comme question. ;)

Comment: Par exemple, banal a deux significations : - l'une très ancienne et féodale est "appartenir au ban" donc au seigneur local, comme les moulins ou les fours banaux. - l'autre, plus récente, en opposition à "spécial", comme les déchets banals par opposition aux déchets nucléaires.